# .htaccess not working in Wordpress

Tags: permalinks, htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to make use of the post name permalink so that visitors can access the page created by the plugin that I'm using.

I've already checked `phpinfo()` and mod_rewrite is listed under the loaded modules section. I also copied the `.htaccess` string given by wordpress and I added it on the `.htaccess` file in the web root directory (which is alongside the `wp-content` directory because I moved the wordpress files outside the wordpress directory).

The `.htaccess` file contains the following:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /devuser/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /devuser/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Any idea what's wrong or where should I be looking?

Comment: What do you mean by "trying to make use of the post name permalink so that visitors can access the page created by the plugin that I'm using"? I don't understand what you want to do.

Comment: Basically the plugin that I'm using creates a page. Something like products page, which should be accessed like: `http://site.com/products` but I'm getting page not found even if I've already setup the `.htaccess` file